# magento 2 add bundle items into cart dynamically with quantity

Tags: magento2, bundle-product

I want to add bundle products with quantity dynamically into cart. 
I am able to add products but quantity is not updated. it is always 1. 
Is there any way to solve this issue.

below code i am using for that.

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById(89,false, null, true);

$bundle_option = [ 1 => array(2,8,18) ];  // 2,8,18 are selection ids, 1 is option id 
$bundle_qty = [ 1 => array(2,3,4) ]; // 2,3,4 are quantity, 1 is option id 

$params = [
    'form_key' => $this->formKey->getFormKey(),
    'product' => 89,
    'bundle_option' => $bundle_option,  // it is working fine 
    'bundle_option_qty' => $bundle_qty,  // logically it will work but in my case it is not working.                
    'qty' => $totalqty
];  

$this->cart->addProduct($product, $params);
$this->cart->save();
```

Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
$product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id, false, null, true);
$this->_cart->addProduct($product, $data);
```

where `$data` is an array as shown below:

```
$data = [
    'qty' => 1,
    'product' => 45,
    'bundle_option' => [
        1 => 4,
        2 => 8, 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 7,
    ],
    'bundle_option_qty' => [
        1 => 1,
        2 => 4, 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 14,
    ]
];
```

the keys inside `bundle_option` and `bundle_option_qty` are indexes, not some ID's. I reckon it doesn't matter what these keys are as long as they correspond to the keys in the other array.

Items inside `bundle_option` array are options ID's and the other contains quantities so in this case we add 1 item ID=4, 4 items ID=8 and so on...

Comment: $data = [ 'qty' => 1, 'product' => 45, 'bundle_option' => [ 1 => 4, 2 => 8, // this is selection ids 3 => 2, 4 => 7, ], 'bundle_option_qty' => [ 1 => 1, 2 => 4, // this is qty 3 => 2, 4 => 14, ] ];

but it is not working, i already tried.

in bundle product, option type is checkbox ( with 5 products selected ) & there is no option e.g User defined quantity [checkbox] ( in magento guide it is mention )

pl. suggest other working solution

pl. help me

Answer (score 0):

$data = [
    'qty' => 1,
    'product' => 45,
    'bundle_option' => [
        1 => 4,
        2 => 8,    // this is selection ids 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 7,
    ],
    'bundle_option_qty' => [
        1 => 1,
        2 => 4, // this is qty 
        3 => 2,
        4 => 14,
    ]
];

but it is not working, i already tried.

in bundle product, option type is checkbox ( with 5 products selected 
) & there is no option e.g User defined quantity [checkbox] ( in magento guide it is mention )

pl. suggest other working solution

pl. help me